# Export CSV file from Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, csv

I am using csv_helper.php file in helpers for exporting. It is grabing the results from mysql but showing the results only instead of downloading !
Here's the csv_helper

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if ( ! function_exists('array_to_csv'))
{
    function array_to_csv($array, $download = "")
    {
        if ($download != "")
        {   
            header('Content-Type: application/csv');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $download . '"');
        }       
        ob_start();
        $f = fopen('php://output', 'w') or show_error("Can't open php://output");
        $n = 0;     
        foreach ($array as $line)
        {
            $n++;
            if ( ! fputcsv($f, $line))
            {
                show_error("Can't write line $n: $line");
            }
        }
        fclose($f) or show_error("Can't close php://output");
        $str = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        if ($download == "")
        {
            return $str;    
        }
        else
        {   
            echo $str;
        }       
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists('query_to_csv'))
{
    function query_to_csv($query, $headers = TRUE, $download = "")
    {
        if ( ! is_object($query) OR ! method_exists($query, 'list_fields'))
        {
            show_error('invalid query');
        }

        $array = array();

        if ($headers)
        {
            $line = array();
            foreach ($query->list_fields() as $name)
            {
                $line[] = $name;
            }
            $array[] = $line;
        }

        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $line = array();
            foreach ($row as $item)
            {
                $line[] = $item;
            }
            $array[] = $line;
        }

        echo array_to_csv($array, $download);
    }
}
```

And here's the controller function:

```
public function exportUser() {
    $this->load->database();
    $query = $this->db->get('user');
    $this->load->helper('csv');
    query_to_csv($query, TRUE, 'toto.csv');
}
```

And in the view page it is showing the results:
user_id,user_name,user_email,user_pass,user_phone,user_country,user_city,user_zip,user_address,user_type,user_status 53,abcdef,abcd@yahoo.com,12,1,,0,,,Student,1 54,aws,abc@yahoo.com,12,12,Afghanistan,Kapisa,,,"Resource Person",0 55,onti,ontika@ya.com,12,12,,0,,,"Registered User",1 56,edf,df@abc.com,12,12,Albania,Bulqize,,dewde,"Admin User",1 58,meena,meena@abc.com,,,,,,,"Registered User",0 
61,nisat,nisat@abc.com,,,,,,,"Registered User",0

but not downloading ! Tried Chrome and mozilla both....

What to do???

Thank you in advance !

Comment: I believe it should be `Content-Disposition: attachment`, not `attachement`.

Comment: Edited ... but still same case :(

Comment: Can you verify the headers are being set correctly? The "Network" inspector in most browsers shows the request and response headers.

Comment: tried this :
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
but no luck !

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying the headers in array_to_csv() funtion:

```
// Disable caching
$time = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s');
header('Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate');
header('Last-Modified: ' . $time . ' GMT');

// Force download
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Type: application/download');

// Set encoding
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=' . $download);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
```

Then after the output section, add an exit:

```
if ($download == "")
{
    return $str;    
}
else
{   
    echo $str;
}
exit;
```

Or try using CodeIgniter's built-in functions:

```
public function exportUser() {
    // Load database and query
    $this->load->database();
    $query = $this->db->get('user');

    // Load database utility class
    $this->load->dbutil();
    // Create CSV output
    $data = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($query);

    // Load download helper
    $this->load->helper('download');
    // Stream download
    force_download('toto.csv', $data);
}
```

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: I've modified my answer to include an option for modifying your csv_helper file.

Comment: i changed csv_helper.php
same case !!

Comment: I've edited to add an exit. If that still doesn't work, try turning on display errors to make sure that nothing's interfering with the headers. Even a PHP warning/notice could cause issues.

Comment: displaying error in index.php
but there is no error !

Comment: I have tried with normal text files also. It seems any kind of file is not downloading !
is there something to enable or disable ??
Please help !

Comment: It's most likely that something is being output before the headers are sent, causing an issue. Even an undefined variable could cause this. Are any errors being displayed or logged? You can enable error logging within the php.ini or CodeIgniter config.php.

Comment: If there aren't any PHP errors, then it's likely a configuration error within the php.ini or on the server. I don't think I can be much help in that case.

Comment: tried a lot of things ... it just killing time no results ! Oh GOD ! :'(